# searching .* in notepad++ to delete between to words

Tags: regex, search, notepad++, wildcard

I have a text

aabbccddeeaaee

I want to delete between aa and ee, but I want the first occurrence to be deleted not the whole thing.

When I search **aa.*e** it finds aabbccddeeaaee but I want aabbccddeea.

Comment: Try `.*?` (non-greedy matching).

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try non-greedy matching:

```
/aa.*?ee/
     ↑     non-greedy matching
```

Normally the `*` quantifier will grab as much as it can--that is what is called greedy matching. To make it grab as little as it can, non-greedily, use the `.*?` variation. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
x?
```

> If used immediately after any of the quantifiers `*`, `+`, `?`, or `{}`, makes the quantifier **non-greedy** (matching the minimum number of times), as opposed to the default, which is **greedy** (matching the maximum number of times).